# Windows Phone SDK8 installation troobleshooting

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I was using Visual Studio 2012 + SDK 8.0 on a PC running Windows 8 (not pro), and I decide to buy another hard drive to install Windows Pro on the sam PC in order to run a Windows Phone emulator on the PC (PC is Asus N550 16Gb RAM and i7 4700 CPU)

I bought a brand new SSD disk, and I installed (fresh) Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit (The OS is genuine and activated)

Then I faced a very annoying issue. The SDK8.0 installation always return an error which is difficult to understand

Cannot post a screen capture since I just created my account on stackoverflow
The error popup says
Setup Failed
Install cannot continue because some required components failed
Please correct the following problem and restart the setup...

And here is the extracted portion from the installation LOG file

[12B8:1530][2013-10-08T09:43:50]: Verified acquired payload: cab0960DD077C2D6FBDD3FFD8F00AB28475 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\cab0960DD077C2D6FBDD3FFD8F00AB28475, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{A2DFDB99-5576-391D-9F62-D1223A41C7F4}v11.0.50727\packages\MobileTools\AddIncoreres\MobileTools_Addincoreres_x86_enu.cab.
[12A4:17CC][2013-10-08T09:43:50]: MUX:  Source confirmed
[12A4:17CC][2013-10-08T09:43:50]: Acquiring package: Windows_MetroMinSDK, payload: Windows_MetroMinSDK, copy from: G:\packages\Windows_SDK\Win8SharedSDKTools.msi
[12B8:1530][2013-10-08T09:43:50]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to verify certificate chain policy status.
[12B8:1530][2013-10-08T09:43:50]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to get certificate chain for authenticode certificate.
[12B8:1530][2013-10-08T09:43:50]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to verify signature of payload: Windows_MetroMinSDK
[12B8:1530][2013-10-08T09:43:50]: Failed to verify payload: Windows_MetroMinSDK at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\Windows_MetroMinSDK, error: 0x800b0101. Deleting file.
[12B8:1530][2013-10-08T09:43:50]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to cache payload: Windows_MetroMinSDK
[12A4:17CC][2013-10-08T09:43:50]: MUX:  Verify Failed.  Retry acquiring, Retry Count: 1 of 3
[12A4:17CC][2013-10-08T09:43:50]: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2146762495 (0x800B0101), Error Message=, Result Detail=, Vital=True, Package Action=Verify, Package Id=Windows_MetroMinSDK
[12A4:17CC][2013-10-08T09:43:50]: Failed to cache payload: Windows_MetroMinSDK from working path: C:\Users\Didier\AppData\Local\Temp{2348da3b-1257-4a83-a554-b094a08d06d9}\Windows_MetroMinSDK, error: 0x800b0101.
[12A4:17CC][2013-10-08T09:43:50]: Application requested retry of payload: Windows_MetroMinSDK, encountered error: 0x800b0101. Retrying...
[12A4:17CC][2013-10-08T09:43:50]: Acquiring package: Windows_MetroMinSDK, payload: Windows_MetroMinSDK, copy from: G:\packages\Windows_SDK\Win8SharedSDKTools.msi
[12A4:17CC][2013-10-08T09:43:50]: MUX:  Reset Result
[12B8:1530][2013-10-08T09:43:50]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to verify certificate chain policy status.
[12B8:1530][2013-10-08T09:43:50]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to get certificate chain for authenticode certificate.
[12B8:1530][2013-10-08T09:43:50]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to verify signature of payload: Windows_MetroMinSDK
[12B8:1530][2013-10-08T09:43:50]: Failed to verify payload: Windows_MetroMinSDK at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\Windows_MetroMinSDK, error: 0x800b0101. Deleting file.
[12B8:1530][2013-10-08T09:43:50]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to cache payload: Windows_MetroMinSDK
[12A4:17CC][2013-10-08T09:43:50]: MUX:  Verify Failed.  Retry acquiring, Retry Count: 2 of 3

I tried to install the big iso file or the small installation file (SDK8.0). Exactly same issue.

Funny enough the same iso file installation was running successfull on the same PC (running windows 8.0 instead of windows 8.1 pro)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this; [MSDN Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/d715ca81-7d15-4de7-8544-3d6d79e318f1/where-can-i-download-the-following-package-win8sharedsdktoolsmsi?forum=wpdevelop#8e3e212d-9916-4855-948f-ccf4ec21449c)

It seems that some certificates on Microsofts end are expired.

Edit; in short;
Set your system date back to September 1st 2013 or earlier.

Comment: Great thanks for the link. It saved my day ! Just to be clear : To solve this issue I just put my clock to 2013, August 1st (instead of current date) and I run again the SDK installation...and it passed !

Comment: Yay! Thanks for the date switch toptip. I was going crazy with the install that wouldn't install.

Comment: HAHAHAH! same - i moved it back a month (for me, 1st of sept). seems to be working now!

Answer (score 2):

Change the date to 30/08/2013 and continued the setup..bingo that did work for me...