# Can't install Visual Studio 2012 Express for Phone 8.0 developement

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have serious problems installing Visual Studio 2012 Express for Phone 8 Developement.

I am getting Fatal Error:

> Emulation Images and Pipe is not being closed error constantly

I've tried downloading from couple of sources and tried offline and online install.

Then I've decided that I will install Visual Studio 2012 express first and then add Phone 8 SDK to it. I had no problems installing Visual Studio 2012 but when I try to install Phone 8.0 SDK I get `Emulation Images error` and I have no idea what to do.

I'm running Widnows 8.0 Pro with this configuration:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU : m 350 @2.27GHZ 
   4,00 GB RAM
   64-bit OS, x64Based processor
   SLAT is supported
```

This is the latest error log with Visual Studio 2012 Express installed and trying to install Phone 8 SDK:

Log File: http://pastebin.com/gj1Bx9fR

Let me know if you need more information.

Now I'm downloading VS Update 3 and I'll try to install this and then SDK after that.

No idea what to do, please help.

---

I've tried the following:

- Changing timestamps
- Different sources (.iso / web)
- Updating OS
- Installing latest SPs
- Registry cleaning / changing hash functions
- Evaluating certificates
- updating Visual Studio
- every forum ever possible

BUMP!

Comment: try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242102/windows-phone-sdk8-installation-troobleshooting

Comment: Changing time does not help.

Comment: another possible reason is obsolete root certificate - check this KB http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2746268

Comment: The log shows that it has trouble with the WP_Images package.  Strongly suggesting that the file on disk is corrupted.  Attempts to re-download the package don't work either.  Getting your machine healthy should be your first priority.  Downloading the ISO instead could be a workaround, but focus on the health of your disk drive first.

Comment: Hans Passant can you tell me more about disk health. I'm not sure how to proceed furhter or what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've saved this with upgrading to Windows 8.1 via Store and then installing Visual Studio 2013 Pro which have Phone 8 SDK built-in. I can run emulator also, but needed to go into BIOS and changed virtual-d-something. :)